# Processing scrolling down the stage

Tags: processing, twitter4j

Following draws using text method tweets to the stage:

```
void DrawTweets() {
  for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size (); i ++) {

    Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);
    String user = (t.getUser()).getName();
    String msg = t.getText();
    text(user + ": " + msg, 20, 15  + i * 45, width - 20, 40);
  }
}
```

The problems is that the tweet count is set to 100 therefore it prints 100 of tweets and they dont show it all on stage. I am looking for some way to scroll through all of them. If you have any ideas, please help me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include the tag of the computer language, framework and platform you are using.

Comment: forget about tweets and think about this in terms of just "things", like rectangles. If you have 100 rectangles, and you can only show five at a time, what do you do? You add an offset for "which rectangle to start at", then draw 5 rectangles from that index, and you add some kind of input control that lets you change that starting offset value, so that when you redraw after changing it, you see a different set of 5 rectangles.